# Set jalali date labels for X axis in matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis

I have to vectors x and y, x is list of date and y is price of something. I'm trying to plot these vectors. but my x axis is terrible. This is my cod:

```
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (20,10)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(u'پارازایلن')
artext = get_display(reshaped_text)
ax.plot(x,y, color='mediumvioletred',linewidth = 8, label=artext)

fig.figimage(im, 43, 425, zorder=100, alpha=1)
#ax.locator_params(axis='x',nbins=5)
#plt.xticks(rotation = 70)
_=ax.legend(loc='lower center')
```

and my output is:
[image]

how can I set this ticks in x axis???

Comment: Use this : `plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')` for rotating x-axis

Comment: `reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(u'پارازایلن')` are strings, not datetime objects, so the API plots every label. The better option is to create the plot with standard datetime values, then extract the labels, convert them, and reset the existing labels.

Comment: I have 1000 tick "@I'mahdi" !!!!